# Source control, live server best practices

Tags: svn, tomcat

I'm working on a project where we're using Tomcat and SVN.  I have my repo checked out in a different directory than my tomcat webapps directory (were the code the server uses lives).  I was told it was a bad idea to checkout a copy of the repository in the webapps directory.  How then can you test live server code when the code the server sees is in /webapps and my repo is located elsewhere?  Currently I have been having to make changes in both my repo and the webapps directory.  What's a good solution for this?

Comment: You could use a build process to deploy the code from repository into Tomcat.

Comment: @Thilo I'm working on a large team and I don't have that option :(. Is there any other way to keep the two folders in sync with each other?  How is the problem typically solved in a real world setting.

Comment: A large team is _real world setting_ you want to use build process - that way each team member knows what needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's a best practice but I've been using (at least) two techniques:

1. Use a [Context Descriptor](http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/c292.html#ADD_CONTEXT) file

This is a file in $TOMCAT/conf directory which tells Tomcat where the app actually is and what's it called (ie. you can even change the context, like have an app called `my-best-app-ever` and deploy it on `localhost:8080/my-second-best-app-ever`.

1. Make a *symlink* of the code to the webapps directory for my test instance of tomcat.

This is quick and effective and hassle-free. Not meant for teams, only localhost.

Comment: You can set custom context params, like configure to autoreload on changes, your own log config, whatever you need. Basically configure your own version of the app.

Comment: awesome, i'll look into this.